# Buying guns from America if I am European

Tags: regulations, firearms

I wanted to ask something related to the gun dealing policies. If I am European, is there a way I can purchase a gun from let's say Daniel Defense (which is American).

**Moved into question from an "answer" by the OP**:
I just wanted to ask If I can buy a gun from an American store If I'm European. I know they allow citizens to purchase firearms, I'm well aware of that. And my question was what are we doing If I'm European

Comment: Are you talking about importing it from an internet purchase?

Comment: Are you asking about the legality of the purchase in America, or the import into your state of residence.  If the latter, where do you live?

Comment: After purchasing the gun (so you know hold it in your hand, somewhere in a gun store in the USA), what do you want to do with it?

Answer (score 1):

The first requirement that must be satisfied to purchase a firearm in the U.S. is that the purchaser must either be a resident of a State within the United States or arrange for the licensed seller to directly export the firearm. From the [Bureau of Alcohol, Tobacco, Firearms and Explosives web site](https://www.atf.gov/firearms/qa/may-nonimmigrant-alien-who-has-been-admitted-united-states-under-nonimmigrant-visa-and):

> A nonimmigrant alien without residency in any State may not purchase and take possession of a firearm. A nonimmigrant alien may only purchase a firearm through a licensee where the licensee arranges to have the firearm directly exported. A nonimmigrant alien who falls within an exception may, however, purchase and take possession of ammunition.
>
> A nonimmigrant alien who has established residency in a State may
>   purchase and take possession of a firearm from an unlicensed person,
>   provided the buyer and seller are residents of the same State, and no
>   other State or local law prohibits the transaction. A nonimmigrant
>   alien with residency in a State may purchase a firearm from a
>   licensee, provided the sale complies with all applicable laws and
>   regulations.
>
> [18 U.S.C. 922(a)(9); 27 CFR 478.29a]

The licensee listed in the first paragraph who must "arrange to have the firearm directly exported" will need a license from the U.S. Commerce department for shotguns or from the U.S. Department of State for rifles and pistols. Additional licensing and customs authorizations would be required from the importing nation.

I answered a [related question on travel stack exchange](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/67702/as-a-tourist-can-i-try-firearms-in-california/67707#67707) regarding possession of a firearm in the U.S. A foreign national who wishes to possess a firearm in the U.S. must be aware of the regulations regarding that possession. Note that possession doesn't mean owning; renting a firearm at a gun range or even sharing a gun at an informal range would constitute possession. Possession means in your control.

A foreign national who improperly possesses a firearm in the U.S. can be subject to significant criminal penalties as well as being banned from returning to the U.S.

As it relates specifically to Daniel Defense, they do have [dealers in European countries](https://danieldefense.com/international-dealers-and-distributors) and, assuming you are permitted to purchase such firearms in those countries, then you could indeed purchase a firearm made by Daniel Defense.

Answer (score 0):

The United States federal government allows citizens and legal permanent residents to purchase fire arms.  Individual States will follow these rules as well, though the restrictions on purchase may differ from State to State, though this is not on grounds of citizen or resident status, it could factor into the difficulty of purchasing.  You may not purchase fire arms if you are convicted of a Felony or a misdemeanor domestic offense or a documented history of recent mental health concerns.  In other cases, there will typically be some court order baring you from purchase, but this is case by case.

Furthermore, while you may not purchase firearms while on vacation to the United States, it may be possible to go to a gun range and legally fire a weapon owned by the range.  This could also depend on state by state, but I do know Hawaii has a large market of ranges that cater to Japanese Tourists who want to do just that on their American Vacations.  Generally these would exist in areas with high foreign tourists locations, though may be off the beaten path as they tend to be in more rural parts of the state than the touristy parts.